# Hyperledger Indy pool connecting android error -> InvalidStateException: The SDK library experienced an unexpected internal error

Tags: android, docker, hyperledger-indy

I have a one question.

I’m trying to connect the Android app to the indy pool, but I see error( Timeout happens for ledger operation) source(https://github.com/jSh4rk/SampleIndyWallet)

I installed indy in AWS(ubuntu 16.04 lts) and after running node with docker

When running docker I entered the command

`docker build --build-arg pool_ip=172.31.37.144 -f ci/indy-pool.dockerfile -t indy_pool`

because I want `172.31.37.144` to be private ip address of my docker container:

`docker run -itd -p 172.31.37.144:9701-9708:9701-9708 -t indy_pool`

In SampleIndyWallet's file MainActivity.java I changed the string ip to public IP of my container.

However, I get error `org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.InvalidStateException: The SDK library experienced an unexpected internal error` in the process of opening connection to the pool.

Comment: I have edited your question to make sure I understand it right. If you find that I changed some of your intended meaning, please readjust. When asking question next time, please use formatting to make question easier to read. Make sure to also avoid anything what's not on point of the question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to Hyperledger Indy from anywhere, as you might already know, you need genesis file. Genesis file specifies IP addresses of the network Nodes and their associated cryptographic data (signatures, public keys...).

When building Indy pool docker with command as you've posted
`docker build --build-arg pool_ip=172.31.37.144 -f ci/indy-pool.dockerfile -t indy_pool`

it's important to specify correct `pool_ip`. The `pool_ip` will become part of genesis file. And when you supply genesis file to indySDK, it will take these IPs and try to establish connection with them. If you are getting error such as `PoolTimeout`, it's likely because these IPs are not reachable from the environment you run IndySDK at.

So by building image as above you are saying: "*Clients connecting to container made of this image will have to be able to reach the container via address `172.31.37.144`*". That might work if you are trying to connect to the pool from other docker container within the same network. But if application is running on your localhost, `172.31.37.144` will not connect anywhere as that's only internal IP address within the docker network.

As I understood, you want to run Indy network in pool and connect to the pool from application running on your host. The easiest way is to make the network reachable on your localhost / `127.0.0.1` by exposing the ports. Let's first build indy network container which will have `127.0.0.1` in its genesis transactions.

`docker build --build-arg pool_ip=127.0.0.1 -f ci/indy-pool.dockerfile -t indy_pool`

Now let's read genesis file of your image and store it locally.

`docker exec indy_pool cat '/var/lib/indy/sandbox/pool_transactions_genesis' > ~/my_genesis.txn`

Next you'll start the pool similarly as you've been doing it, but no need to specify internal ip address of container - it doesn't matter.

`docker run -itd -p 9701-9708:9701-9708 -t indy_pool`

Now you when you start your application and try to connect to the pool, you'll have to specify path to genesis file we created on your localhost.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I knew that if I specified a specific ip when I was doing a docker build, I should also state when I was doing a docker run.
I've been thinking about this a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please click the checkmark to mark this as accepted answer for the question. Thank you